# Reformat the scala code and if/ else statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have written Scala code combined with spark dataframe.
At first, it is working (only when i dont use if else statements). Although its not a clean code and would like to know how can i transform it?

Secondly, the if/ else statement does not work, how can i append the value like in python to a variable above and use it later as a dataframe?

Sorry for i'm a novice in Scala.

```
    %scala

    for(n <- Scalaconfigs){
      var bulkCopyMetadata = new BulkCopyMetadata

      val sourceTable = n(0)
      val targetTable  = n(1) 

      println(sourceTable)
      println(targetTable)
      val df = spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM ${sourceTable}")


      if (sourceTable == "est.Values"){
        val vs1 = df.withColumn("Duration", 'Duration.cast("double")).withColumn("StartUTC", 'StartTimeUTC.cast("bigint")).select('DeviceID, 'DeviceType, 'StartUTC, 'Duration as 'Duration)

      }
      else if  (sourceTable == "est.tests"){
         val vs1 = df.withColumn("DateUTC", 'DateUTC.cast("Timestamp")).select('ID, 'DateUTC as 'DateUTC)

      }

          val writeConfig = Config(Map(
            "url"               -> url,
            "databaseName"      -> databaseName,
            "dbTable"           -> targetTable,
            "user"              -> user, 
            "password"          -> password,
            "connectTimeout"    -> "5",
            "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "100000",
            "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
            "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "600"
          ))

          vs1.bulkCopyToSqlDB(writeConfig)
          //vs1 doesnot take value, when i use if else statements


    }
```

The variable "vs1" cannot be found. That the error. I know its because the variable vs1 is defined in the if else blocks, but how can i use it above. I tried it putting above but i'm not sure about the datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vs1` is inside the local scope and its not visible outside. Declare `vs1` outside and also try using pattern matching instead of `if else`

```
val vs1 = sourceTable match {
  case "est.Values" =>
    df.withColumn("Duration", 'Duration.cast("double"))
      .withColumn("StartUTC", 'StartTimeUTC.cast("bigint"))
      .select('DeviceID, 'DeviceType, 'StartUTC, 'Duration as 'Duration)
  case "est.tests" =>
   df.withColumn("DateUTC", 'DateUTC.cast("Timestamp"))
     .select('ID, 'DateUTC as 'DateUTC)
}
```

Comment: Just a note: If your `sourceTable` isn't "est.Values" or "est.tests" It will throw an Exception